# JQuery Validate Plugin Error - Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, cookies

I am receiving an error when I click submit on the checkout button, which is "Cannot read property 'form' of undefined at n.fn.init.valid".

The error relates to the jQuery plugin, Validate, and the error starts at .form, on the following section of code:

```
i=t(this[0].form).validate();return this.each(function(){e=e&&i.element(this)})
```

I only started using validate yesterday - I have not copied the whole code as it is about 100 lines of minified code.

It doesn't always occur.  Also worth noting is that the error stops occurring if I clear my cookies.

I do wonder if it could be because of the only form element on the page, is a sign-up/log-in section at the end - if logged in then the form element does not appear, so there is nothing to validate?  But again, if I clear my cookies, then log in, I do not get the error.

Has anyone seen anything similar?  And does anyone either know a fix or a workaround?

Comment: `this[0]` does not have a `form` property. The next step is to figure out what exactly `this[0]` is and/or should be, and how it has come to be undefined

Comment: post your js code not the minified validate js